# Spring Rest API Byte[] as a property of returning Object issue

Tags: spring

With Spring Rest I am returning a JSON object with an API endpoint with a byte array of an base64 String property but its returning String data for byte array,however  mapping of HttpMessageConverter is ok when i am taking as input the same with another API
        @PostMapping("/document-add")
        public List addDocument(@RequestBody ArrayList dd, @RequestHeader String sessionId) {
            LOGGER.info("Entered addDocument() -> dd.size= "+dd.size());
            return uploadService.uploadDocument(dd, sessionId);
        }

```
    //@RequestMapping(value="/document-get", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @GetMapping(value="/document-get", produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE) 
    ResponseEntity<ArrayList<BinaryData>> getDocument(@RequestHeader String sessionId,@RequestHeader String documents) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(downloadService.downloadDocuments(sessionId,documents), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        //return downloadService.downloadDocuments(sessionId,documents);
    }

public class BinaryData implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5165348244266958806L;
    private int imageIndex;
    private byte[] data;
    private String error;
    public BinaryData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    /**
     * @param imageIndex
     * @param data
     */
    public BinaryData(int imageIndex, byte[] data,String error) {
        super();
        this.imageIndex = imageIndex;
        this.data = data;
        this.error = error;
    }

    /**
     * @return the imageIndex
     */
    public int getimageIndex() {
        return imageIndex;
    }
    /**
     * @param imageIndex the imageIndex to set
     */
    public void setimageIndex(int imageIndex) {
        this.imageIndex = imageIndex;
    }
    /**
     * @return the data
     */
    public byte[] getData() {
        return data;
    }
    /**
     * @param data the data to set
     */
    public void setData(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    /**
     * @return the error
     */
    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
    /**
     * @param error the error to set
     */
    public void setError(String error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(data);
        result = prime * result + imageIndex;
        result = prime * result + ((error == null) ? 0 : error.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BinaryData other = (BinaryData) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(data, other.data))
            return false;
        if (imageIndex != other.imageIndex)
            return false;
        if (error == null) {
            if (other.error != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!error.equals(other.error))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BinaryData [imageIndex=" + imageIndex + ", data=" + Arrays.toString(data) + ", error=" + error + "]";
//      return "BinaryData [imageIndex=" + imageIndex + ", data==" + data + ", error=" + error + "]";

    }


import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * @author **strong text**
 *
 */
public class DocumentData {

    private String customerId, applicationId, loanId, documentType, docN, financeType;
    private byte[] binData;

    public DocumentData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public DocumentData(String customerId, String applicationId, String loanId, String documentType, String docN,
            String financeType, byte[] binData) {
        super();
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
        this.loanId = loanId;
        this.documentType = documentType;
        this.docN = docN;
        this.financeType = financeType;
        this.binData = binData;
    }

    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getApplicationId() {
        return applicationId;
    }

    public void setApplicationId(String applicationId) {
        this.applicationId = applicationId;
    }

    public String getDocumentType() {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(String documentType) {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }

    public String getDocN() {
        return docN;
    }

    public void setDocN(String docN) {
        this.docN = docN;
    }

    public String getLoanId() {
        return loanId;
    }

    public void setLoanId(String loanId) {
        this.loanId = loanId;
    }

    public byte[] getBinData() {
        return binData;
    }

    public void setBinData(byte[] binData) {
        this.binData = binData;
    }

    public String getFinanceType() {
        return financeType;
    }

    public void setFinanceType(String financeType) {
        this.financeType = financeType;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((applicationId == null) ? 0 : applicationId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + Arrays.hashCode(binData);
        result = prime * result + ((customerId == null) ? 0 : customerId.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((docN == null) ? 0 : docN.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((documentType == null) ? 0 : documentType.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((financeType == null) ? 0 : financeType.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((loanId == null) ? 0 : loanId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DocumentData other = (DocumentData) obj;
        if (applicationId == null) {
            if (other.applicationId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!applicationId.equals(other.applicationId))
            return false;
        if (!Arrays.equals(binData, other.binData))
            return false;
        if (customerId == null) {
            if (other.customerId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!customerId.equals(other.customerId))
            return false;
        if (docN == null) {
            if (other.docN != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!docN.equals(other.docN))
            return false;
        if (documentType == null) {
            if (other.documentType != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!documentType.equals(other.documentType))
            return false;
        if (financeType == null) {
            if (other.financeType != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!financeType.equals(other.financeType))
            return false;
        if (loanId == null) {
            if (other.loanId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!loanId.equals(other.loanId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DocumentData [customerId=" + customerId + ", applicationId=" + applicationId + ", loanId=" + loanId
                + ", documentType=" + documentType + ", docN=" + docN + ", financeType=" + financeType + ", binData="
                + Arrays.toString(binData) + "]";
    }

}
@Post input sample
    [
    {   
    "customerId":"131", 
    "applicationId":"99", 
    "loanId":"9", 
    "documentType":"xlsx", 
    "docN":"OPPO_MOM.xlsx", 
    "financeType":"LM",
    "binData":[85, 69, 115, 68, 66, 66, 81, 65, 66, 103, 65, 73, 65, 65, 65, 65, 73, 81, 66, 55, 107,  89, 97, 76, 87, 121, 69, 87, 53, 70, 122, 88, 55, 43, 80, 105, 50, 105, 67, 89, 48, 47, 57, 116, 54, 53, 119, 65, 68, 122, 70, 99, 102, 66, 52, 83, 54, 50, 122, 70, 71, 115, 118, 73, 110, 122, 97, 112, 101,  65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 74, 103, 110, 65, 65, 66, 107, 98, 50, 78, 81, 99, 109, 57, 119, 99, 121, 57, 106, 100, 88, 78, 48, 98, 50, 48, 117, 101, 71, 49, 115, 85, 69, 115, 70, 66, 103, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 78, 65, 65, 48, 65, 90, 119, 77, 65, 65, 78, 52, 112, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 65, 61, 61]
    }
]

@Get output sample
[
    {
        "imageIndex": 59,
        "data": "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",
        "error": null
    }
]**strong text**
```